# Android: How to split Picture captured from webview in multiple images

Tags: android-webview

I have a webview and I capture the view like this

```
    Picture picture = m_browser.capturePicture();
    Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
                picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas( b );
    picture.draw( c );
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/temp_1.jpg");
        //fos = openFileOutput("samsp_1.jpg", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        if ( fos != null )
        {
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90, fos);  
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Now if the loaded web site is long, for eg. times.com then this image is also too big.

I want to split this image in multiple images and with out reducing the quality.

I would like to get these images in the highest quality possible.

Pls. help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but this will work on VERY long webpages without running out of memory. First, put your webview inside another layout (RelativeLayout rl). Size the RelativeLayout for the image size you want. Then call:

```
rl.draw(canvas);
// do something here to save your bitmap
webview.scrollby(0, rl.getHeight());
```

and repeat that till you're at the bottom of the page!

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height)
```

I allways use this code to cut the a large image to multiple images.

I can use it easy